# How to solve this using arrays and for loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a string given, such as "hello my name is James and what is your name and what is your name"
It should output "hello my name is james and what 4 your 3 6 7 4 8 3"
So Basically what happens is that the if the words get repeated then they get replaced with the position of where the first word occurred. For instance, if the sentence is "the house is the best" it would replace the repeated word which is "the" with the position of where the first "the"  occurred. so it should output "the house is 1 best"

Comment: please give us a solid example and correct expected output.  Your post quality needs to be better if you are to expect good quality answers.  thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: So my given string is "How are you today and are you free tomorrow?" so it should return "How are you today and 2 3 free tomorrow?"

Comment: ive tried using a loop and splitting the string. but after that i don't know what to compare for the if and else statements and i get stuck.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a place for asking people to do the homework for you.

Comment: If you really need a solution to the problem for whatever reason, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/z3mwc8tn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to split the string at every space. You do this with the `split` method.

```
var sentence = "hello my name is James and what is your name and what is your name";
var words = sentence.split(" ");
```

Then you want two nested `for` loops. The first one goes through each word, and the second one checks for each word before it. If they are the same, it makes

```
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (words[i] == words[j]) {
            words[i] = j + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you want to turn the array back into a string. Do this with the `join` method.

```
var newSentence = words.join(" ");
```

This method doesn't work correctly if there is any punctuation or capital letters. Capital letters can be fixed by using the `toLowerCase` method on the original string. Punctuation will be more complicated, I'll be able to figure it out  if you give me some time.

Comment: "That helped, really appreciate it"

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest using `reduce`:

```js
function parse (str){ 
  var found = {}, 
      index = 0; 
  return str
  .split(" ")
  .reduce( (prev, el) => { 
    if(!found[el]){ 
      found[el] = index; 
      prev.push(el) 
    } else { 
      prev.push(found[el]) 
    } 
    index ++; 
    return prev; 
  }, []).join(" ");
}

console.log(parse('Hellow my my my my friend this this not this is not working with UpperCase This My hellow'));
```